# adjective + conjunction + gerund

Tags: gerunds

> The story is neatly complex yet enrapturing. (the audience)
>
> A naughty guy yet making people happy.

Is it correct to put gerund after conjunction and adjective?, I've seen these phrases such as *nice yet affordable cars* but does it have the same rule for gerunds?.

Comment: Enrapturing and making are not gerunds. *making people happy* and *enrapturing* are adjectival here.

Comment: Hi could you show me something to read the rules, I am still confused by this, thanks before.

Comment: A gerund is a verbal noun(Swimming is my hobby), Swimming is a verb, but it has a noun attribute. Enrapting here is an *attributive verb*. It does modify the noun(The story). It's just like you say, "The movie is *interesting*". Interesting here is a verb that functions as an adjective. You may read this wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attributive_verb

Comment: Your first example has "yet" coordinating two constituents (adjectival phrases) which are parallel, so it works, though perhaps a little unwieldy. The second has "yet" coordinating two quite different constituents - A noun phrase with a determiner, and an adjectival clause (or it could be a nominal clause if "making" is a gerund). Either way, the two components are too different in syntax and semantics that it is strange and hard to understand, and possibly not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

> The story is neatly complex ***yet*** entertaining.

The word - *yet* - as used in this sentence is an adverb, the function of it is *Connective Adjunct*. Like a coordinator, it can connect two Adjective Phrase (AdjP) - *complex* and *entertaining*.

The meaning it bears is something like this *though it's complex, it's entertaining*.